# Java Sending BufferedImage through Socket And Converting To Image

Tags: java, image, swing, sockets, javafx

I am trying to send BufferedImage to the socket but it doesn't work but i found a way to send it by doing this:

```
// Capture screen
        Robot clientrobot = new Robot();
        Rectangle robotrectangle = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        BufferedImage image = clientrobot.createScreenCapture(robotrectangle);


        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(image);


        // Send captured screen to the server
        output.writeObject(imageIcon);
        output.flush();
```

But the problem is that i am using javaFX and imageicon is javax.swing that is a problem soo i need to convert it to a JavaFX Image from the ImageIcon soo i found a solution and i think i converted it into the image:

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = (ImageIcon) input.readObject();
                            //java.awt.Image awtimage = imageIcon.getImage();
                            BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                                    imageIcon.getIconWidth(),
                                    imageIcon.getIconHeight(),
                                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                                Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
                                // paint the Icon to the BufferedImage.
                                imageIcon.paintIcon(null, g, 0,0);
                                g.dispose();
                            Image img = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bi, null);
                            RemoteDesktopFormController.desktopimage = img;
```

Soo i send the converted image to other class public static Image img; and then when i try to set the image using this: imgviewhere.setImage(desktopimage); it returns me 3 errors:

1. "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
3. java.lang.NullPointerException

And the error 3 suprised me it says that its null that means the code didn't execute anything soo am i sending a empty null image? i dont think so maybe its a conversion error? i dont think so because i grabbed it from stackoverflow question with 22 votes up soo does anyone have a solution to my problem? and if you need a full error log here it is:

[CLICK ME PASTEBIN LINK](http://pastebin.com/Ps9R8tyy)

If you need something else tell me and i will post it. Thanks

Full RemoteDesktopFormController class code:

```
package application;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

public class RemoteDesktopFormController implements Initializable {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private boolean remotecontrolenabled = false;
    public static boolean receivingdesktop = false;
    public static Image desktopimage;
    //private int desktopreceiverate = 50;

    @FXML
    private ImageView RemoteDekstopFormDesktopImageView;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox RemoteDekstopFormRemoteControlCheckBox;

    public void startreceivingscreen(ActionEvent event){

        if (receivingdesktop == false){

            try {

                MainController.output.writeObject("RECEIVEDESKTOP-configstream");
                MainController.output.flush();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else if(receivingdesktop == true){

            System.out.println("Already receiving desktop!");

        }

    }

    public void stopreceivingscreen(ActionEvent event){

        if (receivingdesktop == true){

            try {

                MainController.output.writeObject("RECEIVEDESKTOP-configstream");
                MainController.output.flush();
                receivingdesktop = false;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else if (receivingdesktop == false){

            System.out.println("You aren't receiving desktop!");

        }

    }

    public void enableremotecontrol(ActionEvent event){

        if (RemoteDekstopFormRemoteControlCheckBox.isSelected() == true){

            RemoteDekstopFormDesktopImageView.setImage(desktopimage);
            remotecontrolenabled = true;

        } else if(RemoteDekstopFormRemoteControlCheckBox.isSelected() == false){

            remotecontrolenabled = false;

        }

    }

    // Remote Control Events
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event){

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event){

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event){

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event){

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event){

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {



    }
```

Comment: For transmitting over sockets, You should serialize your BufferedImage using ImageIO.write(RenderedImage, String, OutputStream)

Comment: Also, it's not clear from the code you posted where/how/why you are getting reflection errors. Where are you using reflection?

Comment: When i was finding a way to transfer the image i did try ImageIO but i have no idea how to use it as i remember it returned me null in the stream i would need a example or something to try it out. And i dont really know what reflection is soo i cant really tell you where it is but i posted the full RemoteDesktopFromController class code if it helps. If you need anything more tell me while i am waiting for a answer i will try to use imageio again

Comment: Also! it would be great if i could somehow convert the image to a string and then from a string to a image again because my stream is using startswith checker it checks what the string is like a command manager and then does something but i have no idea how to do that this question is not about that problem but maybe we can solve it

Comment: Learning how to use `ImageIO` will benefit you much more in the long run than trying to complete this project through work arounds. Focus on your learning

Comment: Oh and i know this question is solved i found out that imageio support only 1 message and has a lot of problems with stream soo i found a way to convert it to string and then send the string and then from the string build the bufferedimage again it also works with other objects not just image for example a text file

Comment: Honestly, I'd write the `BufferedImage` to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` via `ImageIO.write`, write the resulting `byte[]` array to the `Socket` and read it into a `ByteArrayInputStream` and then use this to generate a new `BufferedImage` via `ImageIO.read` on the other side, but that's me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NullPointerException is happenning at `RemoteDesktopFormController.java`, line 76:

```
RemoteDekstopFormDesktopImageView.setImage(desktopimage);
```

So that means that reference `RemoteDekstopFormDesktopImageView` is `null` when the execution passed over that line. Solution: You have to ensure that it is *properly initialized* before an action event is catch.

Comment: Oh god... it is... i am using scene builder and when i was setting this up i set the imageview field and saved it and when i saved it somehow it was null... oh god i feel stupid. Thanks!